# Prevent methods lookup in ancestor chain(method_missing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a code as below

```
def address 
  p "address" 
end 

class Person 
  def method_missing(sym, *args) 
     "#{sym} not defined on #{self}" 
  end

  def name 
    "My name is Person" 
  end
end

p = Person.new 
p.name # => My name is Person 
p.address # => expected output is 'address not defined on # <Person:0x007fb2bb022fe0>' but actual output is 'address'
```

I want to leverage method_missing. But lexical scoping comes to play here. So method_missing becomes obsolete. any workaround?

Comment: You can maybe check `self.class.instance_methods.include?(sym)` inside the method missing. Or, you could define `address` somewhere else other than on the global scope

Comment: Try your code in a file, not in REPL. It works pretty fine as is unless tweaks are set by IRB/Pry (the global scope functions all of a sudden become defined as private methods _of `Object`_.)

Comment: _Sidenote:_ you effectively discard the ability to pass and handle the block to the missing method. The correct signature is `method_missing(m, *args, &λ)`.

Comment: `name` and `address` are both instance methods of `Person`. Therefore, for `p = Person.new`, `p.name` and `p.address` obviously return `"My name is Person"` and `"address"`.  If you want `p.address` to return something else you must change the method `address`. I really don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I guess you could add `class Person; def address; "#{super} not defined on #{self}"; end; end`. Then `Person.new.address` displays 
`"address not defined on #<Person:0x00005a2398d02b20>"`, but seems like unneeded complexity.

Answer (score 0):

As @AlekseiMatiushkin says the code works fine in a file.  If you really need it to work the way you want in irb, you could define address as a class method

```
def self.address 
  p "address" 
end
```

then missing_method will not find it as an instance method of Object, but you can still call `address` as if it were a global function.

Comment: The above code is an just an example. My main pblm is  
p = Person.new    
p.address  </br>    
this should call method_missing only. that is the method lookup should happen within  
Person scope only.